# ORA-12516, TNS:listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a spring boot batch project https://github.com/darkmanAmazigh/spring-boot-batch, when i try to run them, i got this error  message :

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427) ~[spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276) ~[spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.update(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.update(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:357) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:215) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:232) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:124) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:118) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:792) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
        ... 7 common frames omitted
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1771) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:64) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:170) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        ... 45 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:235) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1471) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:61) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        ... 47 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
    ORA-12516, TNS:listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:743) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        ... 52 common frames omitted
    Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
    ORA-12516, TNS:listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack

        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:275) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:264) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1452) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
        ... 64 common frames omitted
```

befor it launch correctly, but now i don't knew why it not work !!

When i change to MySQL that's work correcltly.

why i got this problem just with oracle !!

It's have a problem with the step 2,
step1 finish correctly

need help
Thank you

Comment: This really isn't a Spring issue...it's an Oracle one.

Comment: Share spring configuration.

Comment: the configuration is in guithub

Comment: https://github.com/darkmanAmazigh/spring-boot-batch